# Node/Apollo/GraphQL - advice on using async/await in an Apollo Server plugin

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

Any advice on using async/await in an apollo plugin? I'm attempting to await a twilio service promise and running into the `Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function` babel parser error and unsure how to convert the parent function to be async. Here's the basic layout:

```
export const twilioVerification = async () => {
    return {
        requestDidStart () {
            return {
                willSendResponse ({ operationName, response, context }) {
                    if (['UpdateUser', 'CreateUser', 'SignInByPhone'].includes(operationName)) {
                        const user = response.data[operationName];
                        if (user != null) {
                            await sendVerificationText(user.phoneNumber);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    }
};
```

The above code throws the `BABEL_PARSE_ERROR`. I've attempted a variety of ways to add async to `willSendResponse` and/or `requestDidStart` with mixed unsuccessful results. For reference, here's how I am instantiating ApolloServer as well:

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  context: { driver, neo4jDatabase: process.env.NEO4J_DATABASE },
  schema: schema,
  introspection: process.env.APOLLO_SERVER_INTROSPECTION,
  playground: process.env.APOLLO_SERVER_PLAYGROUND,
  plugins: [
    pushNotifications(firebase),
    twilioVerification(),
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The function that isn't `async` is *your* function. Just add `async` on your `willSendResponse`. Here is one way to do that:

```js
export const twilioVerification = async () => {
    return {
        requestDidStart () {
            return {
                willSendResponse: async ({ operationName, response, context }) => {
                    if (['UpdateUser', 'CreateUser', 'SignInByPhone'].includes(operationName)) {
                        const user = response.data[operationName];
                        if (user != null) {
                            await sendVerificationText(user.phoneNumber);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    }
};
```